# Why the vignette of my package is disapearing after a few time?

Tags: r, package, vignette

I encounter an issue regarding the vignette of a package I am developping in R. Vignette had been created using `usethis::use_vignette`. It is a Rmd file in the `vignettes` directory, and the DESCRIPTION file has the following inside :

```
Suggests:
    testthat,
    knitr,
    rmarkdown
VignetteBuilder: knitr
```

The check throws one warning, but I think it isn't relevant ("'qpdf' is needed for checks on size reduction of PDFs")
Then I build my source package, and obtain a .tar.gz archive. When I install this (either with the graphic interface of RStudio or with `install.packages`), my vignette appears if I use `??my_package` and is listed when I call `vignette()`. The installation process also mentions "installing vignettes" and everything seems ok.

**However, after a few times the vignette just disapear, and is not findable anymore (or listed).** I have not been able to determine what trigger this (this may be after a reboot but not always, sometimes this happens fast sometimes after a few hours...).

I am a bit confused with this, does anyone have an idea?

Many thanks to you!